# Why is WCF is called Windows

Tags: windows, microsoft, wcf

I'm wondering why it isn't called Microsoft Communication Foundation. Does it rely on Windows and will it rely on Windows in the foreseeable future?

Comment: WCF should really be called WTF. :)

Answer (score 5):

Windows Communication Foundation, Windows Workflow Foundation and Windows Presentation Foundation all require the Windows OS.

WCF and WWF services usually run on a Windows Server, and WPF is also windows-only.

Comment: +1 Good point, this makes sense! I never thought of it as I've never asked myself the question. Thanks! =)

Comment: The avatar alone would be worth +1. Good luck the answer is valid as well, so I got a clean conscience :)

Comment: Though Workflow is just called WF to avoid litigation from the World Wide Fund for Nature (WWF). If you don't believe me check out why the US wrestling changed from WWF to WWE.

Comment: Windows is not required for most of the implementation of WCF thanks to Mono Project. http://www.mono-project.com/WCF

Comment: Not true, WCF runs on Mono. (As others said.) This was just branding to make you *think* it only runs on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Just marketing, I remember around when .Net was initially released, they rebranded all the servers (Exchange, Sql Server etc) to be called the ".Net Servers".

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's part of a larger branding strategy by Microsoft. For example, [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation) and [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) are similarly not really tied to "Windows" as such, either.

(You could probably argue that WPF is "more" tied to Windows than the others, but Silverlight shows that much of WPF can be run on other platforms as well)